# Better way to write this in LESS

Tags: css, less

I have this piece of code which, on hover fades out the other li in a list apart from the one in focus. I was able to convert the CSS into LESS.. but I feel the last part needs to be optimised. I've recently started adopting LESS, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
.folder-child li {
    /*some code*/
    opacity: 1;
}

.folder-child:hover li {
    opacity: .33;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.folder-child li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

While trying to convert to LESS i'm not sure how to do it in a more optimized way..

```
.navigation {
  ul {
    .folder-collection.folder {
      .folder-child {

        li {
          /*some code*/
          opacity: 1;

          a {
            /*some code*/
          }
        }

        &:hover,
        &:focus {
          li {
            opacity: .33;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
            transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

.navigation {
  ul {
    .folder-collection.folder {
      .folder-child {
        li:hover,
        li:focus {
          opacity: 1;
          -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
          transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what is the point of replacing that 13 lines of already valid Less code with  40 lines of selector-overbloated nesting festival supposedly doing the same? First thing you should learn about Less (or any other preprocessor) is that while it does allow nesting it should *never* be used just for the sake of nesting.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thanks for comment. I have just started learning LESS and your comment had made it even easier to understand. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a STRICT equivalent, then you can try :

```
.folder-child{
  li{
    /*some code*/
    opacity:1;
    &:hover{
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  &:hover{
    li{
      opacity: .33;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
      transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
    }
  }
}
```